# Apk compilation failed with message "Unresolved reference: FirebaseDatabase" in Android Studio 3.2

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

I`m trying to use Firebase in kotlin project with Android Studio 3.2 canary-17(windows).
Compilation failed with error "Unresolved reference: FirebaseDatabase".

[image]
[image: firebase compilation fail]

My app [build.gradle](https://gitlab.com/illuzor/firebase-bug-test/blob/master/app/build.gradle) and project [build.gradle](https://gitlab.com/illuzor/firebase-bug-test/blob/master/build.gradle)

The Firebase libs are added to gradle, so Firebase classes must be available.

I understood that:

- It happens with all classes from **com.google.firebase.*** package;
- The problem occurs only with Android Studio 3.2 and only with kotlin;
- If I convert my kotlin classes to java - no errors;
- Clean/Rebuild and Invalidate And Restart not help;
- Clean installation of Android Studio not help;
- I can`t reproduce the problem with Android Studio 3.1.X

I created small demo project - https://gitlab.com/illuzor/firebase-bug-test

I have no idea what may be wrong. Maybe a bug of preview version of Android Studio?

Comment: it worked fine in my machine :/ A couple of questions for you: Did you install the new sdk version 28? Did you try restart and clean cache?

Comment: Yes, of course. SDK Platform 28 is installed. Clean/Rebuild and Invalidate/Restart not helps. The problem occurs even after a clean install of Android Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works fine after update to *Android Studio 3.2 beta2*